# "watch her as she passes by" VS "watch her pass by"

Tags: meaning-in-context

The **sentence 1** below is from the lyrics for the song, Just My Imagination by The Temptations.

> **1**. Each day through my window I **watch her as she passes by**.

I wonder if that sentence has any difference in meaning from the sentence below.

> **2**. Each day through my window I **watch her pass by**.

I guess that the **sentence 2** would be greatly much more common in daily life due to the conciseness, and that the only reason the **sentence 1** was used in the song was to match the rhythm. Is there any other difference in meaning?

In case other lines of the lyrics are required to clarify the **sentence 1**'s context, I added the first lines of the lyrics below.

> ***Each day through my window I watch her as she passes by***
>   *I say to myself you're such a lucky guy*
>   *To have a girl like her is truly a dream come true*
>   *Out of all the fellows in the world she belongs to me*
>   *But it was just my imagination*
>   *Runnin' away with me*
>
> *It was just my imagination runnin' away with me*

Comment: It's has to fit the musical line (number of beats): Each day//through my window//I watch  her//as she passes by. As for the argument you present, it's not really true re daily living and conciseness. The two mean the same exact thing. The normal order (non-poetry would be) I watch her every day as she passes by my window.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you. If the two things mean the same thing, which is more commonly and frequently used in real life between ***I watch her as she passes by*** and ***I watch her pass by***?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, I might say either one. Please note though: pass by implies: pass by my house, my window, my car etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two mean different things because they have a different focus.

In the song the speaker is watching ***her*** as she passes by.

In your second sentence, he is watching *her **pass by***.

She is the focus in the first, her passing by is the focus in the second.

That may be just my imagination, but I don't think so.

P.S. There is no linguistic preference for the one or the other, as they have different meanings. *He watched the people passing by his shop window* vs *He watched the people as they passed by his shop window*.  In the first, the focus is on pedestrian foot traffic.  To describe it metaphorically, it's a wide-angle lens that shows the *movement* of the people. In the second, the focus is on the people who happen to be passing by; the lens has a narrower angle; he is looking at the people themselves, as individuals, couples, groups, whatever, *during those moments* when they are passing by.

If the director of a film were to give these instructions to the cinematographer and camera-crew and then let them do their thing:

*We need shots showing **people passing by***

*We need shots showing **people as they pass by***

with the first instruction he *may* end up with a scene showing a steady throng of people, a flowing mass, and with the second instruction he may end up with a series of brief vignettes showing individuals in the stream of pedestrians.

Comment: Thank you for the concise but also groovy answer. :) If in real life, which would be used more? Do you mean, when the speaker wants to talk about the woman, probably the first will be used, and when the action is focused, the second will be used?

Comment: Please see the P.S.

Comment: Thank you so much for the elegant explanation. The description in P.S. itself feels to me somewhat beautiful like a piece of music or a scene of a film, which at the same time explains the difference perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

As you guess, the main reason for "as she passes by" is to fit the meter of the song, which calls for five beats.

For the most part this does mean the same thing as "pass by", however the use of "as she passes" emphasizes the *ongoing* action, rather than just the *recurring* action.

Another example:

> Every morning my son helps our elderly neighbor **cross** the street.
>
> Every morning my son helps our elderly neighbor **as she crosses** the street.

Again, the difference is between helping her *do* some action, and helping her *while* she does some action.  Frequently this makes little difference in meaning, but it is good to recognize the difference in nuance.

Comment: Thank you very much for the kind answer and also for the example case, Andrew. So in terms of significance of the meaning, the sentence with **as** clause would have more emphasis when in a story?

Comment: @SmartHumanism  I don't think it has more *significance*, just a slightly different *emphasis*.  In the context of the song, for example, it's not an important distinction.  The main point of the song is that the narrator is daydreaming about the woman *going past* him.

Comment: I get your point that fundamentally that expression is for the song, not for giving any distinctive meaning from other similar expressions and also that there is very little difference in nuance. Thank you very much for the very helpful explanations, Andrew. I appreciate it.